# Add columns in listview in c#.net

Tags: c#, listview

Can you tell me how to add a column in listview

i have a list view named "_listAvailable",

i need to add a column named "Name" but i dont know how to do it.this is a simple way 
ColumnHeader columnHeader1 = new ColumnHeader();
columnHeader1.Text = "Name";
listView1.Columns.Add(columnHeader1);
but our project they are doing everything differently i wl give my coding page
here for example "Resource Policy" is an example of one column header in listview("_listAvailable")  its name is "_chPolicy"(variable used in coding side) .Its text is taking from resource files (.resx) files

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

using leaf.Utilities;
using leaf.Plugins;
using leaf.DataModel;
using leaf.DataModel.Attributes;
using leaf.DataModel.Exceptions;
using leaf.Controls.Resources;
using leaf.Controls.Dialogs;
using leafControl = leaf.Controls.Controls;

namespace leaf.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Editor displayed in the details pane for associating host systems with a resource policy.
    /// </summary>
    public class ResourcePolicySystemsControl : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
    {
        #region ResourcePolicySystemsLVI

        /// <summary>
        /// ListViewItem class for displaying an item in the listview of 
        /// the ResourcePolicySystemsControl.
        /// </summary>
        public class ResourcePolicySystemsLVI : BaseLVItem
        {
            #region Properties

            /// <summary>
            /// The IResourcePolicy interface of the ManagedDevice associated with this ListViewItem.
            /// </summary>
            public new IResourcePolicy Data
            {
                get
                {
                    return (IResourcePolicy)base.Data;
                }
            }

            #endregion Properties

            #region Constructors and Finalizers

            /// <summary>
            /// Constructor for a ResourcePolicySystemsLVI.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="md">Managed Device item
            /// being displayed.</param>
            public ResourcePolicySystemsLVI(ManagedDevice md)
                : base(md)
            {
            }

            #endregion Constructors and Finalizers

            #region Methods

            /// <summary>
            /// Initially create and update this item and subitems.
            /// </summary>
            protected override void OnUpdate()
            {
                string func = "ResourcePolicySystemsLVI.OnUpdate";
                try
                {
                    if (Data != null)
                    {
                        Text = base.Data.Name;
                        if (SubItems.Count == 1)
                        {
                            SubItems.Add(((IResourcePolicy)Data).ResourcePolicyEnabled.ToString());
                            SubItems.Add(((IResourcePolicy)Data).ResourcePolicyCurrent.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SubItems[1].Text = ((IResourcePolicy)Data).ResourcePolicyEnabled.ToString();
                            SubItems[2].Text = ((IResourcePolicy)Data).ResourcePolicyCurrent.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    base.OnUpdate();
                }
                catch (System.Exception exception)
                {
                    leafDebug.DebugTraceSevere(func, "Exception: " + exception.ToString());
                }
            }

            #endregion Methods
        }

        #endregion

        #region ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI

        /// <summary>
        /// ListViewItem class for displaying an item in the listview of 
        /// the ResourcePolicySystemsControl.
        /// </summary>
        public class ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI : BaseLVItem
        {
            #region Fields

            private static string m_nullString = Managers.ControlStrings.GetString("ManagedDeviceWizard.None");

            #endregion Fields

            #region Properties

            /// <summary>
            /// The IResourcePolicy interface of the ManagedDevice associated with this ListViewItem.
            /// </summary>
            public new IResourcePolicy Data
            {
                get
                {
                    return (IResourcePolicy)base.Data;
                }
            }

            #endregion Properties

            #region Constructors and Finalizers

            /// <summary>
            /// Constructor for a ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="md">Managed Device item
            /// being displayed.</param>
            public ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI(ManagedDevice md)
                : base(md)
            {
            }

            #endregion Constructors and Finalizers

            #region Methods

            /// <summary>
            /// Initially create and update this item and subitems.
            /// </summary>
            protected override void OnUpdate()
            {
                string func = "ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.OnUpdate";
                try
                {
                    if (Data != null)
                    {
                        Text = base.Data.Name;
                        if (SubItems.Count == 1)
                        {
                            if (Data.ResourcePolicy == null)
                                SubItems.Add(ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.m_nullString);
                            else
                                SubItems.Add(Data.ResourcePolicy.Name);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Data.ResourcePolicy == null)
                                SubItems[1].Text = ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.m_nullString;
                            else
                                SubItems[1].Text = Data.ResourcePolicy.Name;
                        }
                    }
                    base.OnUpdate();
                }
                catch (System.Exception exception)
                {
                    leafDebug.DebugTraceSevere(func, "Exception: " + exception.ToString());
                }
            }

            #endregion Methods
        }

        #endregion

        #region Fields

        private IContainer components;

        // Indicates a refresh is necessary.
        private bool _refresh = false;

        // leaf server reference.
        private leaf.Plugins.leafServer _leafServer = null;

        // Gui components.
        private Panel _panelBorder;
        private ContextMenuStrip _cmenu;
        private ToolStripMenuItem _cmenuDistribute;
        private ToolStripMenuItem _cmenuEnable;
        private ToolStripMenuItem _cmenuDisable;
        private SplitContainer _splitter;
        private Label _lblSelected;
        private leafListView _listAvailable;
        private ColumnHeader _chNameAvailable;
        private Label _lblAvailable;
        private leafListView _listSelected;
        private ColumnHeader _chNameSelected;
        private ColumnHeader _chEnabledSelected;
        private ColumnHeader _chCurrentSelected;

        #endregion Fields

        #region Events

        /// <summary>
        /// Event raised when the SelectedObjects have changed.
        /// </summary>
        public event System.EventHandler SelectedObjectsChanged;

        #endregion Events

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the ListView control.
        /// </summary>
        public leafListView ListView
        {
            get
            {
                return _listSelected;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get/set the selected objects for members display.
        /// </summary>
        public object[] SelectedObjects
        {
            get
            {
                return m_selectedObjects;
            }
            set
            {
                OnSelectedObjectsChanging();
                m_selectedObjects = value;
                OnSelectedObjectsChanged();
            }
        }
        private object[] m_selectedObjects = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Selected resource policy the host systems are to be assigned with.
        /// </summary>
        public ResourcePolicy ResourcePolicy
        {
            get
            {
                return m_resourcePolicy;
            }
            set
            {
                if (m_resourcePolicy != null)
                {
                    m_resourcePolicy.Updated -= new EventHandler(m_resourcePolicy_Updated);
                }
                m_resourcePolicy = value;
                if (m_resourcePolicy != null)
                {
                    m_resourcePolicy.Updated += new EventHandler(m_resourcePolicy_Updated);
                }
            }
        }
        private ResourcePolicy m_resourcePolicy = null;
        private ColumnHeader _chPolicy;

        /// <summary>
        /// Get/set the leaf Server object for the connection.
        /// </summary>
        public leaf.Plugins.leafServer leafServer
        {
            get
            {
                return _leafServer;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_leafServer != value)
                {
                    if (_leafServer != null)
                    {
                        _leafServer.ObjectReceived -= new leafServer.ObjectEventHandler(ObjectReceived);
                    }
                    _leafServer = value;
                    if (_leafServer != null)
                    {
                        _leafServer.ObjectReceived += new leafServer.ObjectEventHandler(ObjectReceived);
                    }
                    _refresh = true;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the list of host systems that is currently associated with
        /// the selected resource policy for an OS type.
        /// </summary>
        public DataModelCollection PolicySystemsList
        {
            get
            {
                if (ResourcePolicy == null)
                    return new ManagedDeviceCollection();
                else
                    return ResourcePolicy.ManagedDevices;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the list of host systems that is currently NOT associated with
        /// the current resource policy.
        /// </summary>
        public DataModelCollection AvailableSystemsList
        {
            get
            {
                ManagedDeviceCollection mdc = new ManagedDeviceCollection();
                ObjectArray coll;

                if (ResourcePolicy == null)
                    return mdc;

                if (ResourcePolicy is WindowsResourcePolicy)
                {
                    coll = leafServer.GetObjectsByType(typeof(WindowsSystem));
                }
                else
                {
                    coll = leafServer.GetObjectsByType(typeof(UnixSystem));
                }
                foreach (ManagedDevice dev in coll)
                {
                    if (dev.ImmediateState != ModifiedState.ToBeDeleted &&
                       ((IResourcePolicy)dev).ResourcePolicy != ResourcePolicy)
                        mdc.Add(dev);
                }

                return mdc;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// the resource policy OS node associated with the control.
        /// </summary>
        public ResourcePolicyOSNode Node
        {
            get
            {
                return m_node;
            }
            set
            {
                m_node = value;
            }
        }
        private ResourcePolicyOSNode m_node = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates if an Enable can be performed.
        /// </summary>
        public bool CanEnable
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (ResourcePolicySystemsLVI lvi in _listSelected.SelectedItems)
                {
                    if (!lvi.Data.ResourcePolicyEnabled)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates if a Disable can be performed.
        /// </summary>
        public bool CanDisable
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (ResourcePolicySystemsLVI lvi in _listSelected.SelectedItems)
                {
                    if (lvi.Data.ResourcePolicyEnabled)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates if a Distribute operation can be performed.
        /// </summary>
        public bool CanDistribute
        {
            get
            {
                return this._listSelected.SelectedItems.Count > 0 ||
                   this._listAvailable.SelectedItems.Count > 0;
            }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        #region Constructors and Finalizers

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a ResourcePolicySystemsControl with default settings.  
        /// Must set the ResourcePolicy object before display.
        /// </summary>
        public ResourcePolicySystemsControl()
        {
            // This call is required by the Windows.Forms Form Designer.
            InitializeComponent();

            // Attach to application idle
            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Dileafse(bool dileafsing)
        {
            // Remove selected objects.
            m_selectedObjects = null;

            // Remove application idle handler.
            Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(Application_Idle);

            // Remove object received handler.
            _leafServer.ObjectReceived -= new leafServer.ObjectEventHandler(ObjectReceived);

            // Remove resource policy update handler
            if (m_resourcePolicy != null)
            {
                m_resourcePolicy.Updated -= new EventHandler(m_resourcePolicy_Updated);
            }

            if (dileafsing)
            {
                if (components != null)
                {
                    components.Dileafse();
                }
            }
            base.Dileafse(dileafsing);
        }

        #endregion Constructors and Finalizers

        #region Component Designer generated code
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(ResourcePolicySystemsControl));
            this._panelBorder = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this._splitter = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
            this._listSelected = new leaf.Plugins.leafListView();
            this._chNameSelected = new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader();
            this._chEnabledSelected = new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader();
            this._chCurrentSelected = new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader();
            this._cmenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(this.components);
            this._cmenuEnable = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this._cmenuDisable = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this._cmenuDistribute = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this._lblSelected = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this._listAvailable = new leaf.Plugins.leafListView();
            this._chNameAvailable = new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader();
            this._chPolicy = new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader();
            this._lblAvailable = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this._panelBorder.SuspendLayout();
            this._splitter.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this._splitter.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
            this._splitter.SuspendLayout();
            this._cmenu.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // _panelBorder
            // 
            this._panelBorder.Controls.Add(this._splitter);
            resources.ApplyResources(this._panelBorder, "_panelBorder");
            this._panelBorder.Name = "_panelBorder";
            // 
            // _splitter
            // 
            resources.ApplyResources(this._splitter, "_splitter");
            this._splitter.Name = "_splitter";
            // 
            // _splitter.Panel1
            // 
            this._splitter.Panel1.Controls.Add(this._listSelected);
            this._splitter.Panel1.Controls.Add(this._lblSelected);
            // 
            // _splitter.Panel2
            // 
            this._splitter.Panel2.Controls.Add(this._listAvailable);
            this._splitter.Panel2.Controls.Add(this._lblAvailable);
            // 
            // _listSelected
            // 
            this._listSelected.AllowColumnReorder = true;
            this._listSelected.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
            this._chNameSelected,
            this._chEnabledSelected,
            this._chCurrentSelected});
            this._listSelected.ContextMenuStrip = this._cmenu;
            resources.ApplyResources(this._listSelected, "_listSelected");
            this._listSelected.FullRowSelect = true;
            this._listSelected.HideSelection = false;
            this._listSelected.Name = "_listSelected";
            this._listSelected.ShowItemToolTips = true;
            this._listSelected.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            this._listSelected.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
            this._listSelected.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.List_Enter);
            this._listSelected.ColumnClick += new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnClickEventHandler(this.List_ColumnClick);
            // 
            // _chNameSelected
            // 
            resources.ApplyResources(this._chNameSelected, "_chNameSelected");
            // 
            // _chEnabledSelected
            // 
            resources.ApplyResources(this._chEnabledSelected, "_chEnabledSelected");
            // 
            // _chCurrentSelected
            // 
            resources.ApplyResources(this._chCurrentSelected, "_chCurrentSelected");
            // 
            // _cmenu
            // 
            this._cmenu.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this._cmenuEnable,
            this._cmenuDisable,
            this._cmenuDistribute});
            this._cmenu.Name = "_contextMenuStrip";
            resources.ApplyResources(this._cmenu, "_cmenu");
            this._cmenu.Opening += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.contextMenuStrip_Opening);
            // 
            // _cmenuEnable
            // 
            this._cmenuEnable.Name = "_cmenuEnable";
            resources.ApplyResources(this._cmenuEnable, "_cmenuEnable");
            this._cmenuEnable.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.EnableClick);
            // 
            // _cmenuDisable
            // 
            this._cmenuDisable.Name = "_cmenuDisable";
            resources.ApplyResources(this._cmenuDisable, "_cmenuDisable");
            this._cmenuDisable.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DisableClick);
            // 
            // _cmenuDistribute
            // 
            this._cmenuDistribute.Name = "_cmenuDistribute";
            resources.ApplyResources(this._cmenuDistribute, "_cmenuDistribute");
            this._cmenuDistribute.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DistributeClick);
            // 
            // _lblSelected
            // 
            resources.ApplyResources(this._lblSelected, "_lblSelected");
            this._lblSelected.Name = "_lblSelected";
            // 
            // _listAvailable
            // 
            this._listAvailable.AllowColumnReorder = true;
            this._listAvailable.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
            this._chNameAvailable,
            this._chPolicy});
            this._listAvailable.ContextMenuStrip = this._cmenu;
            resources.ApplyResources(this._listAvailable, "_listAvailable");
            this._listAvailable.FullRowSelect = true;
            this._listAvailable.HideSelection = false;
            this._listAvailable.Name = "_listAvailable";
            this._listAvailable.ShowItemToolTips = true;
            this._listAvailable.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            this._listAvailable.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
            this._listAvailable.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.List_Enter);
            this._listAvailable.ColumnClick += new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnClickEventHandler(this.List_ColumnClick);
            // 
            // _chNameAvailable
            // 
            resources.ApplyResources(this._chNameAvailable, "_chNameAvailable");
            // 
            // _chPolicy
            // 
            resources.ApplyResources(this._chPolicy, "_chPolicy");
            // 
            // _lblAvailable
            // 
            resources.ApplyResources(this._lblAvailable, "_lblAvailable");
            this._lblAvailable.Name = "_lblAvailable";
            // 
            // ResourcePolicySystemsControl
            // 
            this.Controls.Add(this._panelBorder);
            this.Name = "ResourcePolicySystemsControl";
            resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.ResourePolicySystemsControl_Load);
            this._panelBorder.ResumeLayout(false);
            this._splitter.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this._splitter.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this._splitter.ResumeLayout(false);
            this._cmenu.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes the update handler from the selected objects.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnSelectedObjectsChanging()
        {
            if (m_selectedObjects != null)
            {
                foreach (ResourcePolicy rp in m_selectedObjects)
                {
                    rp.Updated -= new EventHandler(DeviceUpdated);
                    foreach (ManagedDevice md in rp.ManagedDevices)
                        md.Updated -= new EventHandler(DeviceUpdated);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fills in the list view control with the appropriate managed
        /// device objects and button display, and raises the SelectedObjectsChanged event.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnSelectedObjectsChanged()
        {
            _refresh = true;
            if (m_selectedObjects != null)
            {
                foreach (ResourcePolicy rp in m_selectedObjects)
                {
                    rp.Updated += new EventHandler(DeviceUpdated);
                    foreach (ManagedDevice md in rp.ManagedDevices)
                        md.Updated += new EventHandler(DeviceUpdated);
                }
            }
            if (SelectedObjectsChanged != null)
            {
                SelectedObjectsChanged(this, new System.EventArgs());
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Populate the available list and the selected list.
        /// </summary>
        public void FillOutListViewCtrl()
        {
            string func = "ResourcePolicySystemsControl.FillOutListViewCtrl";
            ManagedDeviceCollection list = new ManagedDeviceCollection();

            try
            {
                if (leafServer == null)
                    return;

                _listSelected.BeginUpdate();
                _listAvailable.BeginUpdate();

                #region populate the selected list

                // Collect selected items.
                object[] selected = new object[_listSelected.SelectedItems.Count];
                _listSelected.SelectedItems.CopyTo(selected, 0);

                // Clear listview.
                _listSelected.Items.Clear();

                // Add systems.
                ResourcePolicySystemsLVI item;
                foreach (ManagedDevice md in PolicySystemsList)
                {
                    item = new ResourcePolicySystemsLVI(md);
                    item.Update();
                    foreach (object obj in selected)
                    {
                        item.Selected = (((ResourcePolicySystemsLVI)obj).Data == item.Data);
                        break;
                    }
                    _listSelected.Items.Add(item);
                }

                // Sort list.
                _listSelected.Sort();

                // Ensure selected items are visible.
                if (_listSelected.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    _listSelected.SelectedItems[_listSelected.SelectedItems.Count - 1].EnsureVisible();
                    _listSelected.SelectedItems[0].EnsureVisible();
                }

                #endregion

                #region populate the available list

                // Collect selected items.
                selected = new object[_listAvailable.SelectedItems.Count];
                _listAvailable.SelectedItems.CopyTo(selected, 0);

                // Clear listview.
                _listAvailable.Items.Clear();

                // Add systems.
                ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI item2;
                foreach (ManagedDevice md in AvailableSystemsList)
                {
                    item2 = new ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI(md);
```

Comment: Hello Peter. Select your code and click on the code button (101010).  Also - this is too much code for any question, try to cut it down to the relevant bits. Thanks.

Comment: One question : Do you think anyone will ever read all your code ?

Comment: I've reformatted the code sample so that you can see which bit is the actual question.  However the sample is too long to be of much use to the question, and too long for StackOverflow, so it is truncated.

Comment: here the listview name is "_listAvailable" and one column name is "Resource Policy" and it is used on code as "_chPolicy"..i need to add one more column 
like Resource Policy,,the new column name is Name

Comment: Your team *really* needs to learn model-view separation. It's very difficult to follow what is supposed to be happening here.

Comment: Buddhism suggests there's a golden path between two extremes. You've gone from too long to too short. I hope this is an accident (and you can roll back - there's a button for that). Try to show the minimal amount of relevant code, explain your problem, what you want, and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple actually everything is coming.the reason why its not coming at runtime we are referring the old DLL not the new DLL ,,,then how should it come,,sorry to disturbing you guys

Answer (score 2):

Use `ListView.Columns.Add()`

Comment: this is the simplest way i already mentioned in my question,,but here
in my project they r doing some other way

Comment: I assume you use this sytem at work, so why don't you just ask the person that designed it ? Did he left ?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
this._listAvailable = new leaf.Plugins.leafListView();
```

implies that your control is derived from `ListView` (in fact, we can't know that for sure, it could be a whole other class with a similar api).
This makes every answer you'll get speculative - it's possible your class behaved differently than a `ListView` (for example, it might change some methods or properties)

Comment: exactly i added those code also in our questions ,,but i didnt get anything